# Prepare() Statement isn't working PHP (SQL Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working into a Php Script to create fields in an online database, and the prepare() statement isn't working so I think I might fail in the query as I'm not good using SQL, here is the function;

```
function createQuestion($CAT, $PREG, $RESP1, $RESP2, $RESP3, $RESPC) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`ID`, `CAT`, `PREG`, `RESP1`, `RESP2`, `RESP3`, `RESPC`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ? , ?, ?, '?, ?)";
  if ($stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql)) {
    echo "prepare works okay!";

    $stmt->bind_param("isssss", $CAT, $PREG, $RESP1, $RESP2, $RESP3, $RESPC);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
  } else {
    echo "prepare isn't working."
  }
}
```

Apart from others errors specified in other classes, I'm getting the "prepare isn't working."

Comment: @DaveChen nothing wrong with inserting `NULL` for auto-increment columns

Comment: Just saw that the mistake was just a simple typo. Oops though, I meant only for primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement has a typo in it:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`ID`, `CAT`, `PREG`, `RESP1`, `RESP2`, `RESP3`, `RESPC`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ? , ?, ?, '?, ?);
```

Note the single `'` mark in the `VALUES(...)` section?  Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`ID`, `CAT`, `PREG`, `RESP1`, `RESP2`, `RESP3`, `RESPC`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```